# How to run all tests in one file for different data in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I am using cypress 12.3. I have written page level validation and e2e tests for my application. I want to achieve following - For page level validation, i have written 10 tests. I want to run these tests for 3 brands. For one brand, url hit - run all tests > then url hit for second brand and run all tests.

I tried following way :

1. Hitting url in before each - did not work. It hit all 3 url and run tests on last url.
2. If i put for loop above each it block - it works but for each test i have to hit url.

Please help me with designing it in better way.

```js
let brands = ['a', 'b', 'c']
describe('Page level validation', () => {
      before(() => {
        //brands.forEach(openUrl) {});
      });

      brands.forEach((b) => {
        it('validate UI', () => {
          openurl(b)
          // test 1
        })
      });

      brands.forEach((b) => {
        it('validate all field error message', () => {
          openurl(b)
          // test 2
        })
      });

      brands.forEach((b) => {
        it('validate all valid values', () => {
          openurl(b)
          // test 3
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap everything you want to repeat in a function, and call that function from your `.forEach()`

```js
function myTestSuite(brand) {

  describe('Page level validation', () => {
      before(() => {
        openurl(brand)
      });

        it('validate UI', () => {
          // test 1
        })

        it('validate all field error message', () => {
          // test 2
        })

        it('validate all valid values', () => {
          // test 3
        });
  ...
}

let brands = ['a', 'b', 'c']
brands.forEach(myTestSuite)      // start all the tests
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, I'd use [Cypress Lodash](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/_) ([specifically `_.times()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#times)) to iterate over the brands and run the tests.

```js
let brands = ['a', 'b', 'c']
describe('Page level validation', () => {
  // run this iteration the same amount of times as the length of brands
  Cypress._.times(brands.length, (index) => {
    const brand = brands[index]; // define brand for ease of use
    
    beforeEach(() => {
      openurl(brand); // this assumes you have some custom logic to handle opening the url.
    });

    // use string interpolation to insert brand into test name
    it(`validates the UI for brand ${brand}`, () => {
      // test code here
    });

    // other tests
  });
});
```

Using Lodash for something like this may seem like overkill, but I've found that using Lodash to handle "dynamically" generating test executions work better than other methods of iterating.